# Where are the settings for which applications are loaded as part of the Pantheon Desktop?

Tags: system

NB: I'm not talking about startup applications. I mean, how does the system know which applications to start as part of the Pantheon destkop, such as which panel, dock, etc.

I'm only seeing `gala` and `gnome-settings-daemon` in `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/pantheon.session`, so I figure it must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pantheon uses a component called Cerbere as a watchdog type service that launches and monitors the additional desktop components. By default, the processes it starts and monitors are: wingpanel, plank, and slingshot-launcher. These are configurable through *dconf-editor* or *gsettings*. Take a look at the *monitored-processes* property in the *org.pantheon.desktop.cerbere* schema.

```
gsettings get org.pantheon.desktop.cerbere monitored-processes
```

Comment: So where is cerbere told to start with the session? This is what I'm trying to get to.

Comment: It's launched as an autostart process when the session loads. The default session autostart processes are located in `/etc/xdg/autostart`. If for some reason you didn't want it to start, you could remove the desktop file: `sudo rm -f /etc/xdg/autostart/cerbere.desktop`. This would give you just a wallpaper when you login. To add it back run: `sudo ln -s /usr/share/applications/cerbere.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/cerbere.desktop`

Comment: thanks. I was trying to solve a problem with wingpanel not starting on login. I'm currently running Pantheon on Ubuntu (I have another laptop for running elementary but haven't installed it yet).